# Zip archive trouble in constrained PowerShell 5.1 environment

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm creating a PowerShell script to do a search-and-replace modification of a JSON file contained within a zip package created and consumed by a specialty application. Most of the script is working well, but replacing the modified JSON file in the zip package is proving difficult. The JSON file to be modified is contained within a directory at the root level of the zip file. My environment is Windows 11 which is fairly closed down due to being on a hospital network. I can't install any applications on my computer, and PowerShell is in constrained language mode.

Initially I tried to completely replace the zip file by deleting the old zip file and creating a new one from the temp directory where I initially extracted the archive before doing the search-and-replace. However, the application consuming the zip file proves to be very fussy in which zip files it accepts, and there seems to be something about the zip file produced by Compress-Archive it doesn't like, so it refused to accept that zip. I tried to extract and recompress the zip file which was output by the script using the archive handling functionality in Windows Explorer, and my application readily accepted that zip file. So it seems like Compress-Archive is doing something weird to the zip files it creates.

Secondly, I tried to do Compress-Archive -Update with the entire directory containing the extracted files, and the initial zip file as the target. That resulted in every file in the archive being duplicated, and the application consuming the zip certainly didn't like that. I also tried this using a new directory only containing the modified JSON file in its subdirectory, but again the file was duplicated in the zip, and my application refused to accept it.

Thirdly, I tried to do Compress-Archive -Update with only the modified JSON file, and the initial zip file as the target. This resulted in the modified JSON file placed in the root of the zip file, and not touching the original JSON file in its subdirectory location. The application consuming the zip now accepted the zip file, but only read the original, unmodified JSON file from the subdirectory, ignoring the updated file in the root of the zip.

How can I either make Compress-Archive create a zip file which is more compatible, or do an -Update without either duplicating the file(s) in the zip or putting the modified JSON file only into the root of the zip file?

Edit: This is the error I get when trying to force my application to open the zip file when replacing the file and not updating it. It's the same when using -CompressionLevel NoCompression

```
-----[InnerException]--------------------
Sequence contains no matching elements
-----[InnerException - StackTrace]--------------------
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at DIPS.OpenEhr.Forms.IO.FormReader.Read(ZipFile zipFile)
   at DIPS.OpenEhr.Forms.IO.FormReader.Read(String path)
   at DIPS.ArenaEhr.Designers.Wpf.Client.EhrClient.FileRepositoryBuilderEhrClient.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<GetFormAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Edit 2: These are the contents of respectively the original zip file (manually unzipped), and the temporary directory created by the script after the modification of the relevant file, both got using `Get-ChildItem`:

Original zip:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant-2.2.0 -Recurse      


    Directory: .\Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant-2.2.0


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
da---l        04.03.2024     11:57                Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant_2_2_0
da---l        04.03.2024     11:57                META_INF


    Directory: .\Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant-2.2.0\Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant_2_2_0


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---l        16.02.2024     14:48          14245 form_dependencies.json
-a---l        16.02.2024     14:48         257808 form_description.json
-a---l        16.02.2024     14:48          34050 form_layout.json
-a---l        16.02.2024     14:48          27968 form_script.js


    Directory: .\Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant-2.2.0\META_INF


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---l        16.02.2024     14:48           1308 MANIFEST.MF
```

Temp directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\AppData\Local\Temp\1dfacedf-8f54-4708-a8ce-6ec66bd6d75f -Recurse                                         


    Directory: .\AppData\Local\Temp\1dfacedf-8f54-4708-a8ce-6ec66bd6d75f


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        04.03.2024     11:55                Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant_2_2_0
d-----        04.03.2024     11:55                META_INF


    Directory: .\AppData\Local\Temp\1dfacedf-8f54-4708-a8ce-6ec66bd6d75f\Allergen_immunterapi_konsultasjon_variant_2_2_0


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        16.02.2024     14:48          14245 form_dependencies.json
-a----        04.03.2024     11:55         257842 form_description.json
-a----        16.02.2024     14:48          34050 form_layout.json
-a----        16.02.2024     14:48          27968 form_script.js


    Directory: .\AppData\Local\Temp\1dfacedf-8f54-4708-a8ce-6ec66bd6d75f\META_INF


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        16.02.2024     14:48           1308 MANIFEST.MF
```

Edit 3: Adding the exact `Compress-Archive` syntax used for case 1 in the original post:

```
Compress-Archive -Path $tempDir\* -DestinationPath $formZipPath -Force
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the app’s log files with the Powershell zip files? There’s not really enough information to make a guess at the problem *but* you could try ```-CompressionLevel NoCompression``` in case the app doesn’t like the default Powershell compression (“Optimal” I think), and check the file paths inside the zip - Windows Explorer adds an extra folder level sometimes - maybe your app expects the file in that exact path? And maybe the tech supports for the app can confirm for you what compression algorithms (store, shrink, deflate, etc) and file paths they support in the zips…

Comment: Does `Expand-Archive` produce exactly the same directory structure as the original file?

Comment: "This resulted in the modified JSON file placed in the root of the zip file, and not touching the original JSON file in its subdirectory location." What if you put the JSON file in an actual subdirectory named just like it is in the zip file, and then provide that full path (not just the JSON file name) to Compress-Archive-Update?

Comment: @mclayton I've added the error message from my application in the question. Using -CompressionLevel NoCompression results in the exact same error message as when not using it.

Comment: @lit yes, it does.

Comment: @MarkAdler Trying a variation of my "Secondly" paragraph from the original question, running ```Compress-Archive -Path $tempDir\* -Update -DestinationPath $formZipPath``` where $tempDir only contains the directory and file I want to update. What happens is that the modified file is added to the zip file, in the correct location, but *in addition to the original, unmodified file*. Weirdly the application does accept this zip file, but it uses the original file instead of the modified one.

Comment: Judging by the error in your update, it’s almost definitely a path issue inside the zip - the stack trace looks like it’s trying to find a file with the path and name in your original zip file but it’s not in that exact same location in your modified file. Can you add the original folder structure to your question, the exact ```Compress-Archive``` command you’re using and the resulting zip file for comparison?

Comment: @mclayton, thanks for responding! I've added the directory structures of the (manually extracted) original zip file and of the temp directory created by the script after modifying the relevant JSON file. When you say "and the resulting zip file", do you mean the actual zip file, or some representation of its directory structure?